# Custom Woocommerce Tracking Form

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce has a default tracking form that lets customers see their order status.

But I'm looking to replace the Email request with Billing Phone Number (which value should be `billing_phone`)

Any idea how to change? It seems it's not that easy to change `order_email` with `billing_phone`.

Here is the part in woocommerce/order/tracking-form.php

```
<p class="form-row form-row-first">
    <label for="orderid">
        <?php esc_html_e( 'Order ID', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
    </label>
    <input class="input-text" type="text" name="orderid" id="orderid" value="<?php echo isset( $_REQUEST['orderid'] ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['orderid'] ) ) : ''; ?>" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Found in your order confirmation email.', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
</p>
<?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
<p class="form-row form-row-last">
    <label for="order_email">
        <?php esc_html_e( 'Billing email', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
    </label>
    <input class="input-text" type="text" name="order_email" id="order_email" value="<?php echo isset( $_REQUEST['order_email'] ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['order_email'] ) ) : ''; ?>" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Email you used during checkout.', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
</p>
<?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple solution for this. Since the core WC process is to get the email input and to compare it against the order billing email.
Unfortunately, I could not find an easy way to override it.
But you can consider adjusting the copy of the template file in your theme folder to get a response from your code rather than WC.

to do this, you will need:

1. Change the nonce field in the form, so the action will be customized (then you will be able to "catch" and handle it from the server-side:

wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-order_tracking_custom', 'woocommerce-order-tracking-custom-nonce' );

2. Copy (to your functions.php) and adjust the method `output` from `class-wc-shortcode-order-tracking.php`

---

```
public static function output( $atts ) {
            // Check cart class is loaded or abort.
            if ( is_null( WC()->cart ) ) {
                return;
            }
...
...
        

wc_get_template( 'order/form-tracking.php' );

}
```

**To something like this:**

```
add_action('init', 'handle_tracking_request');
function handle_tracking_request(  ) {
        // Check cart class is loaded or abort.
        if ( is_null( WC()->cart ) ) {
            return;
        }

        $nonce_value = wc_get_var( $_REQUEST['woocommerce-order-tracking-custom-nonce'], wc_get_var( $_REQUEST['_wpnonce'], '' ) );

        if ( isset( $_REQUEST['orderid'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $nonce_value, 'woocommerce-order_tracking_custom' ) ) { 

            $order_id    = empty( $_REQUEST['orderid'] ) ? 0 : ltrim( wc_clean( wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['orderid'] ) ), '#' ); // WPCS: input var ok.
            $order_phone = empty( $_REQUEST['order_phone'] ) ? '' : sanitize_email( wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['order_phone'] ) ); 

            if ( ! $order_id ) {
                wc_print_notice( __( 'Please enter a valid order ID', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
            } elseif ( ! $order_phone ) {
                wc_print_notice( __( 'Please enter a valid phone', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
            } else {
                $order = wc_get_order( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shortcode_order_tracking_order_id', $order_id ) );

                if ( $order && $order->get_id() && ( $order->get_billing_phone() ) === strtolower( $order_phone ) ) {
                    do_action( 'woocommerce_track_order', $order->get_id() );
                    wc_get_template(
                        'order/tracking.php', array(
                            'order' => $order,
                        )
                    );
                    return;
                } else {
                    wc_print_notice( __( 'Sorry, the order could not be found. Please contact us if you are having difficulty finding your order details.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
                }
            }
        }

        wc_get_template( 'order/form-tracking.php' );
    }
```

I didn't tested it, and hope it will work. You may need to adjust it further. let me know if it helped you